# What is the most helpful beginner android book/website out there?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm an experienced iPhone(c#) and j2me programmer at a cell phone company. I'm looking to purchase a book for the company to use to train new hires after they start working here or even for experienced developers to help get started.

Are there any books / websites that you recommend to get started? Most important would be ones that focus on the Layouts, since that seems to be the most difficult to get started with.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

commonsware is a great resource he is constantly updating his books with new goodies
http://wares.commonsware.com/index.html

Also hello android is another great book
http://www.pragprog.com/titles/eband3/hello-android

Comment: Recommendations for learning resources [are off-topic for stackoverflow.com Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). However, this information [could be ok as part of a tag wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214338/997587).

Answer (score 2):

This isn't for purchase, but since you mention websites, http://www.anddev.org is a great site that has a number of tutorials that range from beginner to advanced and there's a fairly established community of developers there as well.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues swears by this book: [Professional Android 2 Application Development 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470565527).